# How can I add author name in the bottom right corner to a quote in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to add the author's name of the quote in the bottom right corner after the quote ends. I used bold tag and it did work but I want to do it without using the bold tag. Here's the sample code :

```html
<div class="container mx-auto flex px-3 py-24 md:flex-row flex-col items-center">
 <p>“No matter what you achieve, what you want to aspire to be, or how famous and powerful you become, the most important thing is whether you are excited about each and every moment of your life because of your work and people around you.”
                <br>
                <b style="float: right;">- Sushant Singh Rajpoot</b>
  </p>
            
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<div class="container mx-auto flex px-3 py-24 md:flex-row flex-col items-center">
 <p>“No matter what you achieve, what you want to aspire to be, or how famous and powerful you become, the most important thing is whether you are excited about each and every moment of your life because of your work and people around you.”
                <br>
                <span style="float: right;">- Sushant Singh Rajpoot</span>
  </p>
            
  </div>
```